# Images were not displayed in hero card in MS Teams

Tags: botframework

I am using hero card to display the result to the user for their questions but it's not displaying in MS Teams channel.

[image: Teams]

It's working in Skype.

[image: Skype]

Is there any issue in BOT framework regarding this?
And is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be the issue with the `http://` and `https://`

```
cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: "https://<ImageUrl1>"));
```

Just use the url as https://
and

```
ThumbnailCard plCard = new ThumbnailCard()
{
           Title = "I'm a thumbnail card",
           Subtitle = "Pig Latin Wikipedia Page",
           Images = cardImages,
           Buttons = cardButtons
};
```

Comment: I have used https://  only. it works with delay. I noticed that switching the conversation tab it loads the image to me.